# Windows Forms - MdiClient scroll bars not automatically appearing as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbars, mdiparent, mdichild

I'm writing a windows forms application in C# whereby some windows utilities can be launched (e.g. CMD prompt, Registry editor, Events Viewer etc) and placed in an MdiClient control on the main form.

Everything is working great except that the scroll bars in the MdiClient control aren't automatically appearing when a child window falls beyond the MdiClient's borders. If the child windows were windows forms then I know that the MdiClient's scroll bars would automatically appear as expected. I've tried many things, including some complex workarounds.. and i'm beginning to think there must be something i'm completely overlooking.

I have attached some sample code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MdiClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient mdiClient = new System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient();
            mdiClient.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            mdiClient.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            this.Controls.Add(mdiClient);

            int processID = StartCMD();
            AddToMDIClient(processID, mdiClient.Handle);
        }

        private int StartCMD()
        {
            int processID = -1;

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = process.StartInfo;
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

                try
                {
                    process.Start();
                    processID = process.Id;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }

            return processID;
        }
        private void AddToMDIClient(int processID, IntPtr mdiClientHandle)
        {
            try
            {
                Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processID);

                int numberOfAttempts = 0;
                while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle) && numberOfAttempts < 30)//max of 3 seconds
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    process.Refresh();

                    numberOfAttempts++;
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 1, 1, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);

                    SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, mdiClientHandle);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,
            int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
        public const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = /*SWP_NOMOVE | */SWP_NOSIZE;

        public const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    }
}
```

The screenshot below shows that when the CMD window is moved so its borders are outside the borders of the MdiClient there are no scroll bars:

Please see this link for the image: http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/75rMVJMCWRg_s_DFF6LmNg?authkey=Gv1sRgCIKRlsu8xuDh8AE&feat=directlink

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Shady

Comment: The screenshot link is broken.

Comment: The link has been updated now.

Answer (score 1):

Without the screenshot it is hard to say, but I think the way you create the MDIParanet is way too complicated.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient mdiClient = new System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient();
       //  mdiClient.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       // mdiClient.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
       // this.Controls.Add(mdiClient);

       this.IsMdiContainer = true;

        int processID = StartCMD();
        AddToMDIClient(processID, mdiClient.Handle);
    }
```

If you need the Client, you can filter it from Controls.

Another problem might be setting a MDIChild as TOP_MOST, I don't think that's a good combination.

Comment: Here is the image:

http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/75rMVJMCWRg_s_DFF6LmNg?authkey=Gv1sRgCIKRlsu8xuDh8AE&feat=directlink

I tried not using HWND_TOPMOST and still no scroll bars appear in the parent window.

I'm not sure what to make of your code excerpt. All I see if that the code for the MdiClient is commented out and this.IsMdiContainer was added. I have tried adding this.IsMdiContainer with no success.

Comment: My code was incomplete, just 'setting up' MDI the nomal way was safer. Note hat while you set the parent of the Cmd Windows, they probably don't end up in the Client's Controls list. If a part of the MDI logic is handled by WinForms then that  could be the problem.

Comment: If anyone can provide a working example of a CMD window being a child of a Windows Form somehow and for the scroll bars in the parent window to behave as expected that would be appreciated. The scroll bars are the only problem I am having.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some testing and it work ok for me was long as I have Autoscroll = true in the forms properties.

Also, I noticed if you enlarge the form and move the command window to say the bottom right it will not show the scroll bars, it will only when you minimize the form past the command windows (see screenshots below)

Screenshot 1
http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/rfwm-S8y06Fl3HFNshgj3g?feat=directlink

Screenshot 2
http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/y6qkN9Jj19vDGFNkTuL4FQ?feat=directlink

Also, can you set on the Form's properties AutoScrollMinSize, so that you always have scroll bars in the form is smaller than the size set

Hope that helps

Josh

Comment: "Also, I noticed if you enlarge the form and move the command window to say the bottom right it will not show the scroll bars, it will only when you minimize the form past the command windows (see screenshots below)"

This is what my problem is. I've been trying to find a solution using AutoScollMinSize but it's not easy..

Any other tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Shady, been thinking and have a few ideas, just wanted to check to see what you are trying to achieve? Do you want the scrollbars to appear as soon as the bottom right of the child form goes past the bottom right of the parent form?

Josh

Comment: I would like the scroll bars to appear whenever the child form goes beyond any border of the parent form (top, right, left and bottom). Currently I have a timer that resizes the parent form twice a second (increments width by 1px then decrements width by 1px) and this forces the scroll bars to appear. But this is not what i was hoping to have to do of course.